# TinyMCE rails asset pipe line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, asset-pipeline

I am using Rails 4  with tinymce - everything works fine in development mode but when I run as production - rails asset pipe line does not set the path right or somewhere I don't understand it right.

I put tinymce downloaded folder in vendor/assets/javascripts/

In my manifest file included //= require tinymce/tinymce.min

While running in production environment - it is looking for **/assets/tinymce/plugins/**
and 
**/assets/tinymce/themes/**

I tried using tinymce-rails but that also does't seems to be working in production.

how I can resolve path that rails asset pipe line requires?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like in tinymce config you can disable loading theme and language:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea.editor',
    language_load: false,
    theme: function(){} // no theme
  });
```